# How to use lambda flatMap() in Java with Spark 2.1

Tags: java, python-2.7, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, flatmap

I am porting over a Python app to Java and are stuck on the correct way to implement a Lambda `flatMap()`. I am parsing through IP logs and need to split on ' ' (space).

My environment:

- Spark vrs 2.1
- IntelliJ
- Java 8
- jdk 1.92

What I have is:

Load the dataframe:

```
Dataset<Row> MyLog = spark.sql("Select RecordNumber, IpAddress from Table);
MyLog.createOrReplaceTempView("MyLog");
```

now attempt lambda flatmap()

```
Dataset<String> Mylog2 = Mylog.flatMap(e -> String.asList(e.split(' ')));
```

I have tried several variances of this to include:

```
Dataset<Row> Mylog2 = Mylog.flatMap(e -> Array.asList(e.split(' ')));
Dataset<String> Mylog2 = Mylog.flatMap(lambda(e -> String.asList(e.split(' '))));
```

etc.

The original python looked like this:

```
Mylog2 = Mylog.rdd.flatMap(lambda(x,y): ((x,v) for v in y.split(' ')))
```

I would appreciate any insight into the correct way to implement this in Java using Spark

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

what about:

```
Dataset<String> Mylog2 = Mylog.flatMap(row -> java.util.Arrays.stream(row.getString(1).split(' ')).iterator(), Encoders.STRING());
```

but which column do you want to split? On IpAddress?

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. Yes it would be on the IP.